# TrendNet TEG-S16D port to Unifi AP freezes causing connectivity loss

Tags: networking, port, wireless-access-point, switch

I needed more ports so I upgraded from a TEG-S80DG to a TEG-S16D (unmanaged switch btw) and started encountering this problem.  The port which is connected to a Unifi AP is "freezing" causing all connectivity to go down, and thus causing a wifi outage in the house every few days.  The only solution is to plug the AP into another port which fixes the issues or cycle the switch.  If I plug the AP into another port the "frozen" or "stuck" port stays lit and only by cycling the switch does the frozen port get into a normal state.  Anyone had a similar issue?  Is this thing a dud?  It is not happening on any other ports except the one the AP is connected to, and I've tried 3 different ports with the same results after a few days.

Comment: Is there any configuration that applies to only that port? Have you reset (not to be confused with "restarted") the switch to its default configuration?

Comment: @root switch is unmanaged, so there is no configuration.